# how does find's -printf statement work?

Tags: find

```
find /home/lead_admin -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -nr | head -10
```

in the above statement what exactly does `-printf '%s %p\n'` do?

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual (section _ACTIONS_) ?

Comment: @don_crissti, `-printf` is specific to the GNU implementation of `find`, so `info -- find -printf` to get to its documentation would seem more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

From `man find`:

> `-printf format`
>   True; print format on the standard output, interpreting ‘\’ escapes and ‘%’ directives.  Field widths and precisions can be specified as with the ‘printf’ C function.  Please note that many of the fields are printed as %s rather than %d, and this may mean that flags don’t work as you might expect.  This also means that the ‘-’ flag does work (it forces fields to be left-aligned).  Unlike -print, -printf does not add a newline at the end of the string.  The escapes and directives are:
>   ...
>   `\n     Newline`
>   ...
>   `%p     File's name`
>   ...
>   `%s     File's size in bytes`

From that, I would take `-printf '%s %p\n` to mean that it prints the file's size in bytes, followed by a space, followed by the file's name, followed by a newline.